# DOF in cycle render shows in solid view but not in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, depth-of-field

Hi I'm rather new to blender and have seen a lot of tutorials now on Youtube and done a thorough research here on the topic Depth of Field. I also created the first renders but have a problem applying depth of field.

I inserted an empty object called FocusPoint and set up the camera details with focus on FocusPoint and an aperture of 5.6. When switching on DOF for viewport in the properties panel under shading I see a DOF in camera view with solid texture. When switching to rendered preview or when rendering with F12 the DOF is not visible. BTW also when changing the aperture afterwards nothing changes also in solid view.

All the tutorials on applying DOF do just the same but it seems to work for them. I am using Cycles Render.

I don't understand what I didn't get. Do I need to do another customization?

I have stripped down the file to just a box and set the FocusPoint to the upper front edge.
Here is the screen showing both views: [image: Screen showing both views]
The blend file lies [here](http://www.andreasprott.de/dof_test.blend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case i recommend you to change F-stop to radius in the "Aperture" settings. You'll immediately see the blur.

BUT!

Firstly, you should invert your normals: --> ctrl-n
Youl'll find that's working correct.

Secondly, learn blender basics before doing experiments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing aperture from F-Stop to radius did the trick. So that is a bug!? As a photographer I would have liked to use known metrics.
DOF is also a "basic" for me coming from photography. The posted file was just a simple made up example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: PS: Your remark on normals I don't understand. They are facing to the outside because for this example I just added a cube.

Comment: @Andreas, i mean that the normals of the cube are facing inside. To see them correct - apply scale and rotation of your object - ctrl-a. 
Here's a link for a screenshot [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g-aVnXXQQ9ZBLlqjoPZtCVjl_2d47wud)

Answer (score 0):

The size of your block must be huge, so small f stop would mean a lot, imagine changing f stop and trying to get blur over 2 buildings, the 1st building itself would blur just after your set focal length...makes sense?